# Camera lookAt vector

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl, three.js

I'm working with a Three.js Perspective Camera and I need to get the point the camera is looking at.

How can I calculate it using camera's matrix/rotation vector?

Comment: The camera is looking in a direction, and hence at many points along that ray. Which point are your referring to?

Comment: An arbitary point I think, I need just the direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The camera is looking down it's internal negative z-axis. So pick any point on the camera's negative z-axis, like so:

```
var point = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 );
```

Now convert that point from camera space into world space like so:

```
point.applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorld );
```

Note: This gives a point the camera is looking at. To get the direction in which the camera is looking, see [Three.js: Get the Direction in which the Camera is Looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813902/three-js-get-the-direction-in-which-the-camera-is-looking/14816480#14816480)

EDIT: Updated for three.js r.59

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a beginner, so with all these matrices is quite a mess ;-)

Comment: Can I use the same procedure (with point = (0,1,0)) to calculate the UP vector of the camera?

Comment: If I understand your question, the answer is 'yes'.

Comment: DEPRECATED: Matrix4's .multiplyVector3() has been removed. Use vector.applyMatrix4( matrix ) or vector.applyProjection( matrix ) instead.

Comment: @MicahDelaneBolen Thanks for the heads-up. Answer updated with the correct function.