# Get viewing direction of viewer by the time

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to regtreive viewing directions of viewer when play a 360 video by aframe platform.The Output can be midpoint value of FOV( field of View)... Does anyone know how to do it? Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

If you start out with the panorama example from the A-Frame homepage, you can change it like this to obtain the angle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Panorama</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Panorama — A-Frame">
    <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aframe/0.5.0/aframe.js'></script>

    <script>
      AFRAME.registerComponent('theta', {
          tick: function (time, timeDelta) {
            var camera = this.el.object3D.children[0]
            vector = camera.getWorldDirection();
            theta = Math.atan2(vector.x,vector.z);
            console.log(theta);
          },
      });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-camera theta></a-camera>
      <a-sky src="puydesancy.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

(via [Three.js: Get the Direction in which the Camera is Looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813902/three-js-get-the-direction-in-which-the-camera-is-looking) )