# Camera lookAt **get** method

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

How can I get the lookAt camera position? I know that there's an answer in another question that say something like to get `cam.matrix[8]`, but I can't believe that this is the **right** way to do it, so...

How can I get this values correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense to me. `lookAt` method should not affect the position of anything

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813902/three-js-get-the-direction-in-which-the-camera-is-looking/14816480#14816480 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696963/three-js-set-and-read-camera-look-vector/15697227#15697227

Comment: pailhead it's because I wanna to make some calcs that involve the camera "looking at" position.

@WestLangley It helps, thanks.